# Scala play withSession deprecated

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm migrating from slick 2.1 to 3.0. As you know the function `withSession` has been deprecated.

How can I change code bellow:

```
def insert(vote: Vote) = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
  insertWithSession(vote)
}
def insertWithSession(vote: Vote)(implicit s: Session) = {
  Votes.insert(vote)
}
```

I've got compile error on `Votes.insert` and the error is:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter s: slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api.Session
```

At last, Is there any document other than [official link](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0-M1/upgrade.html) helping me to migrate. I need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using play-slick for slick integration with play.

You can look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick for more details.

Add the slick and jdbc dependencies in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0"
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc4"
)
```

Add the postgres config in your application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/yourdb?user=postgres&password=postgres"
```

Now define your models like the following,

```
package yourproject.models

import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

case class Vote(subject: String, number: Int)

class VoteTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Vote](tag, "votes") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def subject = column[String]("subject")
  def number = column[Int]("number")

  def * = (id.?, subject, number) <> (Vote.tupled, Vote.unapply)
}

class VoteRepo @Inject()()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  val db = dbConfig.db
  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  val Votes = TableQuery[VoteTable]

  def insert(vote: Vote): DBIO[Long] = {
    Votes returning Votes.map(_.id) += vote
  }

}
```

Now your controller will look something like,

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import yourproject.models.{VoteRepo}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}

class Application @Inject()(voteRepo: VoteRepo) extends Controller {

  def createProject(subject: String, number: Int) = Action.async {
    implicit rs => {
      voteRepo.create(Vote(subject, number))
        .map(id => Ok(s"project $id created") )
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What I must add to use Postgre as my database driver?